# React class components - conditional styling based on props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, styling

I'm working with older versions of material-ui with no possibility to upgrade.

I am trying to change the background of the Paper component based on a few combinations of the props.  I don't think it's complicated to require use of the makeStyles HOC. Is this possible?

I think the problem is this line:
classes={{ root: correctBackgroundColor.root }}

but the documentation on the https://v0.material-ui.com/#/components/paper unhelpfully says  "Other properties (not documented) are applied to the root element."

```
import React from "react";

const correctBackgroundColor = {
  root: {
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    border: "1px solid lightgrey",
    backgroundColor: props => {
      if (props.ledIsOn === true && props.ledColorType === "Green") {
        return "#00FF00";
      }
      if (props.ledIsOn === true && props.ledColorType === "Orange") {
        return "#FFA500";
      } 
    }
  }
};

class ColorChange extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    let textToRender = (
      <Paper
        id={this.props.id}
        classes={{ root: correctBackgroundColor.root }}
      />
    );
    return (
      <div>
        <Typography variant="p" className={classes.typography_root}>
          {this.props.textLabel}
        </Typography>
        {textToRender}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(ColorChange);
```

there is a sandbox at : https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-bell-oyzsn  TIA!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I hope i got you right. There are two things you should put attention to:

First, `correctBackgroundColor` does not recognize `props` because this is out of scope, therefore, I would recomment to change it into a function, pass the props to it, and make the function return a `style object`.

Second thing, I would use `style` when applying the object to `Paper`, so the style of that paper would be a call to `correctBackgroundColor` with the `props`, like this:

```
<Paper id={this.props.id} style={correctBackgroundColor(this.props)} />
```

Final code:

```
import React from "react";
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography/Typography";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper/Paper";

const styles = theme => ({
  typography_root: {
    fontSize: 12,
    margin: 10
  }
});
const correctBackgroundColor = props => {
  let bgSwitch = "none";
  if (props.ledIsOn === true && props.ledColorType === "Green")
    bgSwitch = "#00FF00";
  if (props.ledIsOn === true && props.ledColorType === "Orange")
    bgSwitch = "#FFA500";
  if (props.ledIsOn === true && props.ledColorType === "Red")
    bgSwitch = "#FF0000";
  if (props.ledIsOn === true && props.ledColorType === "Grey")
    bgSwitch = "lightGrey";
  return {
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    border: "1px solid lightgrey",
    backgroundColor: bgSwitch
  };
};

class ColorChange extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    let textToRender = (
      <Paper id={this.props.id} style={correctBackgroundColor(this.props)} />
    );
    return (
      <div>
        <Typography variant="p" className={classes.typography_root}>
          {this.props.textLabel}
        </Typography>
        {textToRender}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(ColorChange); //with styles injects classes props with styles contained.
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-microservice-n5dwg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)